# What are the calculations to move in 2D relative to the camera direction?

Tags: math, language-agnostic

How do I go in the horizontal direction the camera is facing in radians, according to which of the four WASD keys are pressed? W goes forwards, A goes left, S goes back, and D goes right

It would be annoying if in say Minecraft, pressing W made you walk North instead of whichever way you're facing

Comment: depends on your camera representation if it is matrix then you just use its basis vectors... see [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, from your answer it seems like you already have a grasp on what you need to do. But for the sake of anyone else coming here who has never done this before, I will start with the basics.

#### The Math

Lets say you have a player that wants to move forward. They instinctively know pressing "forward" allows them to move in the direction of the camera.

However when designing a game, it is not just as simple as incrementing a value on one axis. What if they turn around? Are at a 90 degree angle? What if they are facing north east?

To do this you must understand how **sine** and **cosine**, interact with circle and angles.

**Sine** takes an angle and plots out a point on a circle. It then measures the distance from that point to the **X-Axis**.

**Cosine** does the same, but instead of measuring the distance to the X-Axis it measures to the **Y-Axis**.

[image: sine and cosine plotted on circle]

(sin = red, cos = green)

You can see here that as the Direction approaches North, the **red** line will grow while the **green** shrinks. This is what we want. If we are facing directly north, we do not want to move east or west at all.
And the farther right we turn, the more the green line extends. Causing us to move *East* more.

If we can determine the angle we are facing, we can determine how much on each axis we want to move the Player.

Note that sin and cos return a value between **-1** and **1**, so to move the player faster than that, multiply the resulting values by the player's speed.

#### The Code

To move **forward**:

```
moveForward(direction) {
    z += cos(direction) * playerSpeed;
    x += sin(direction) * playerSpeed;
}
```

(If we were working on a 2D game, we would move **X** instead of **Z** and **Y** instead of **X**)

Now that we know how to move forward, moving **backward** is straightforward (no pun intended).

```
moveBackward(direction) {
    z -= cos(direction) * playerSpeed;
    x -= sin(direction) * playerSpeed;
}
```

(Notice how we subtract on **both** axes, this is because if we are facing North-East - and we are walking backward - we would want to move South-*West*.)

For moving **right**:

```
moveRight(direction) {
    z -= cos(direction) * playerSpeed;
    x += sin(direction) * playerSpeed;
}
```

For moving **left**:

```
moveLeft(direction) {
    z += cos(direction) * playerSpeed;
    x -= sin(direction) * playerSpeed;
}
```

There you have it! We now can determine any movement vector based on an input angle!

#### Things to pay attention to:

Make sure you know what angle measurement you are using. In most cases it is going to be in [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), so don't try to use degrees unless that is what your sin/cos functions are expecting.

Make sure you know the "[handedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule#:%7E:text=Coordinates%20are%20usually%20right%2Dhanded.&text=For%20left%2Dhanded%20coordinates%20the,axis%20the%20system%20is%20clockwise.)" of your coordinate system as well. For example in some environments the **Y-Axis** is forward/back. And the **Z-Axis** is up and down. Or East is **negative** X and West is **positive** X.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is this.

```c
const signed char Z = WKeyIsPressed-SKeyIsPressed, X = DKeyIsPressed-AKeyIsPressed;
if (Z || X) {
    const float Direction = ((HorizontalViewAngleRadians-(Z-1)*M_PI/2)*(Z != 0)+(HorizontalViewAngleRadians-X*M_PI/2)*(X != 0))/((Z&&X)+1)+(X == 1 && Z == -1)*(float)M_PI, Speed = 0.0625F;
    XLocation -= sinf(Direction)*Speed;
    ZLocation += cosf(Direction)*Speed;
}
```